# SQL - Retrieve id of most recently modified posts

Tags: sql

Given the following SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[posts]
(
   [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
   [date_posted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [date_modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [content] [text] NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_posts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [id] ASC )
)
```

How can I retrieve the post id of the most recently modified post for each user?

Comment: Just a simple Select consisting of id, user_id, and date_modified. I'm not sure about the CONSTRAINT though. Wouldn't the most recently modified records be in ascending order already?

Comment: Look up aggregate functions, specifically `MAX()`

Comment: Do I need MAX() in this case? This what I've got so far: Select * from posts GROUP BY user_id  Order by date_modified desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the most recent modified post for every user by using `row_number()`

```
select * from (
    select * ,
    row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date_modified desc) rn
    from posts
) t1 where rn = 1
```

**Edit** it appears you're using mysql, which doesn't support `row_number()`. You can use `not exists` instead

```
select * from posts p1
where not exists (
    select 1 from posts p2
    where p2.user_id = p1.user_id
    and p2.date_modified > p1.date_modified
)
```

Sidenote

```
Select * from posts GROUP BY user_id Order by date_modified desc
```

The query above might appear to work but it's actually unreliable because you can not influence which row from a group is returned via `order by`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set
>   occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect
>   which values within each group the server chooses.

Comment: I get a sytnax error
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by user_id order by date_modified desc) rn
    from posts
) t1 where ' at line 3

Comment: This query actually works: Select * from posts GROUP BY user_id Order by date_modified desc What is the difference compared to your solution?

Comment: @Hannes your create table syntax led me to believe you're using sql-server, see update

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Select 
    Id
    ,[User_id]
    ,[Date_Posted]
    ,[Date_Modified]
    ,[Content]
From [dbo].[posts] posts
where date_modified = (select Max(date_modified) from posts2
                        where posts.[User_id] = posts2.[User_id])
```

Comment: Also an error here: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[User_id]
    ,[Date_Posted]
    ,[Date_Modified]
    ,[Content]
From [dbo].[pos' at line 3

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would do it.

```
Select * from dbo.posts where user_id = ? Order     by date_modified desc limit 1
```

Comment: This only applies to a single user. How can I get the modified posts for all users?

Comment: Pass an array of ids and instead of user_id = ? Use user_id IN ?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that returns the post ids for ALL users in this table

Comment: Is it not possible to pass an array of ids??

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for a single query that returns the post IDs for all users.

Comment: While what I have advised will work as a single query returning all users called for, see if this is acceptible for you: SELECT * FROM dbo.posts GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY date_modified DESC

Comment: Just posted the same thing above. I think this should do the trick.